# Merge list of dictionary by common key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to merge the list of dictionaries inside a list based on a key. The sample input for the same looks like:

```
my_data = {
    "id_1": [
        {"er": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80}},
        {"ef": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80}},
        {"er": {"app": "falsk", "port1": 81}},
        {"ef": {"app": "django", "port1": 85}}
    ],
    "id_2": [
        {"er": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80}},
        {"ef": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80}},
        {"er": {"app": "falsk"," port1": 81}},
        {"ef": {"app": "django", "port1": 85}}
    ]
}
```

I am trying to get an output looks like this:

```
res_data = {
    "id_1": [
        {"er": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80, "app": "falsk"," port1": 81}},
        {"ef": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80, "app": "django", "port1": 85}}
    ],
    "id_2": [
        {"er": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80, "app": "falsk", "port1": 81}},
        {"ef": {"ip": "myhost", "port": 80, "app": "django", "port1": 85}}
    ]
}
```

Is there any easy method in python to achieve it?

**Update : Solution based on comments and initial thoughts**

```
def merge_list_of_dict(data):
    merged_dict = dict()

    for k, v in data.items():

        tmp_tems = dict()
        for j in v:
            for ki, vi in j.items():
                if ki in tmp_tems:
                    tmp_tems[ki].update(vi)
                else:
                    tmp_tems[ki] = vi
        merged_dict[k] = tmp_tems
    return merged_dict
```

Comment: Your input data doesn't match your output, I assume "er":{"app":"django","port":85} is supposed to be ef?

Comment: No, you can't have two identical keys `"port"` in the same dictionary.  One of them will replace the other.

Comment: Good catch, I didn't notice the two ports, otherwise the thing to do is call update on the dictionary with the second dictionary

Comment: Nice catch. Updated the data

Answer (score 2):

The approach I've taken is to build a temp dictionary using `update` to merge dicts based on their key. I then create an `output` dictionary and then print that, to return to the `list` formatting. You could directly print `{'entry': [tmpdict]}` on each loop if you wanted to skip that step. I've used `pprint` to make the output clear, but it's obviously optional.

```
import pprint

my_data= {'id_1': [{'er': {'ip': 'myhost', 'port': 80}},
          {'ef': {'ip': 'myhost', 'port': 80}},
          {'er': {'app': 'falsk', 'port1': 81}},
          {'ef': {'app': 'django', 'port1': 85}}],
 'id_2': [{'er': {'ip': 'myhost', 'port': 80}},
          {'ef': {'ip': 'myhost', 'port': 80}},
          {'er': {'app': 'falsk', 'port1': 81}},
          {'ef': {'app': 'django', 'port1': 85}}]}

output = {}
for entry, data in my_data.items():
    tmpdict = {}
    for item in data:
        for k,v in item.items():
            if not k in tmpdict:
                tmpdict[k] = {}
            tmpdict[k].update(v)

    output[entry] = [tmpdict]

pprint.pprint(output)
```

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for the solution.I got to try out somewhat similiar.I am trying to make more compact like using a list/dict comprehension
    def merge_list_of_dict(self,data):
        merged_dict = dict()

        for k, v in data.items():

            tmp_tems = dict()
            for j in v:
                for ki, vi in j.items():
                    if ki in tmp_tems:
                        tmp_tems[ki].update(vi)
                    else:
                        tmp_tems[ki] = vi
            merged_dict[k] = tmp_tems
        return merged_dict

Comment: Best to put new code and comments as edits to the question, as code in comments is unreadable!